# Error when creating configurable product programmatically in multi-storeview site

Tags: magento2

I am trying to create a configurable product using the following code:

```
// Load Configurable Product
    $product = $this->product->create();
    $product = $product->load($parentId);

    $attributeValues = [];
    $options = $this->attribute->getOptions();
    array_shift($options); //remove the first option which is empty
    foreach($options as $option) {
        $attributeValues[] = [
            'label' => 'Option',
            'attribute_id' => $this->attribute->getId(),
            'value_index' => $option->getValue(),
        ];

    }

    $configurableAttributesData = [
        [
            'attribute_id' => $this->attribute->getId(),
            'code' => $this->attribute->getAttributeCode(),
            'label' => $this->attribute->getStoreLabel(),
            'position' => '1',
            'values' => $attributeValues,
        ],
    ];

    $this->output->writeln('ConfigurableOptions:'. print_r($configurableAttributesData, true));

    $configurableOptions = $this->optionsFactory->create($configurableAttributesData);

    $extensionConfigurableAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
    $extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductOptions($configurableOptions);
    $this->output->writeln("Linking deals:".print_r($simpleDeals['ids'], true));
    $extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductLinks($simpleDeals['ids']);
    $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionConfigurableAttributes);
    $this->output->writeln('Extension attributes set');
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
```

All of the simple deals have been created at that point as well as the attribute options. This is what the $configurableAttributesData array looks like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [attribute_id] => 215
        [code] => deal_options
        [label] => Option
        [position] => 1
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Option
                        [attribute_id] => 215
                        [value_index] => 128
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Option
                        [attribute_id] => 215
                        [value_index] => 129
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Option
                        [attribute_id] => 215
                        [value_index] => 130
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

But when running the code, everything runs smoothly except for the $this->productRepository->save($product); part which gives this error:

Option values are not specified.

Any idea what might cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok this error was caused by the simple deals not having values in the attribute used for the configurable deal connection to the simple deals.

I simply had to run this (with the option ID that you create for that deal):

```
$product->setCustomAttribute('deal_options',$optionId);
```

When creating the simple deals

Comment: Hi @maxl, Do you know include gallery_image  into your data for save.